# When executing a perl search and replace on the command line, how do I lower case a matched token?

Tags: regex, perl, search, replace, lowercase

I have a file with lines like

```
TEST=value
```

I would like to do a search and replace such that I replace the first token with its lower case equivalent.  So the above would be transformed into

```
prefix/test —output value
```

I tried the below

```
perl -pi -e ’s/(.*)=(.*)/prefix\/lc($1) —output $2/g' .env
```

But evidently “lc” is being interpreted literally because the result is

```
prefix/lc(TEST) —output value
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can use `\L...\E` escapes, which work in a double-quoted context (see it [in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators))

```
perl -i -pe's{(.*)=(.*)}{prefix/\L$1\E --output $2}g' .env
```

Note that `\L` keeps lower-casing all following characters until it runs into `\E` so it's safer to have `\E` even though it's not needed here. I used `{}{}` delimiters  so to not have to escape `/`'s.

Or, in particular if there's more to do, evaluate *code* in replacement part via `/e` modifier, like

```
perl -i -pe's{(.*)=(.*)}{"prefix/" . lc($1) . " --output $2"}eg' .env
```